# Angular2 how can I get a hook on the styles associated to a specific element

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a component that improves my news ticker directive that you can see [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/4mBHkIVTetC0kh34JOyT/). Instead of passing a limited number of style attributes to the directive like this:

```
<div class="tickerContainer myStyles">
  <div ticker [trigger]="'onClick'" [text]="myText" [speed]="15" [padding-right]="0" [size]="40"></div>
</div>
```

I would instead prefer to style the element along side the css of the component in which it is used. Basically style it just like you would any other element in your application:

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div class="my-component-class">
      <ticker-container>
        <ticker>{{displayText}}</ticker>
      </ticker-container>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .my-component-class{
      width: 100%;
    }
    ticker-container{
      width: 50%;
    }
    ticker {
      font-size: 24px;
      padding: 4px 10px;
    }
  `]
})
export class MyComponent  {
  displayText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
}
```

The problem that I am hitting is that I can display the styles of the original `<ticker>` component via `<ng-content>` but I cannot apply the styles to the generated element (the duplicate element generated to 'tick' behind the first element). I've tried via a component generator and using various configuratinos of the `:host`/`::shadow`/`>>>` style commands.

I could solve this if I knew how to copy all of the styles from the other element. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `ticker-container` and `ticker` components, set the `ViewEncapsulation` to `none`:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: ticker-counter,
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

This will tell Angular not to encapsulate these elements in the Shadow DOM so parent styles can trickle down to it.